# Custom Analyzer - Attribute Based Mapping - Nest 2.X

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to know the way to add a custom analyzer as an attribute which will allow me to automap instead of manual mapping in elastic search nest client 2.x

Example:
I have a model

public class Employee
    {

```
    [String]
    public string FName {get; set;}

    [String(Analyzer = "my_analyzer")]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Where do I define my_analyzer so that it can be auto mapped?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your analyzer when you're creating the index.

```cs
public void CreateIndex(string indexName)
{
    // Define the analyzer
    var customAnalyzer = new CustomAnalyzer();
    customAnalyzer.Tokenizer = "my_tokenizer"; // add a tokenizer
    customAnalyzer.Filter = new List<string>();
    customAnalyzer.Filter.ToList().Add("lowercase"); // add some filters

    // Add the analyzer to your index settings
    var request = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
    request.Settings.Analysis.Analyzers = new Analyzers();
    request.Settings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add("my_analyzer", customAnalyzer);

    // Create the index
    ElasticClient nestClient = new ElasticClient();
    var indexResponse = nestClient.CreateIndex(request);
}
```